# Falling Speed of earth towards an object?

Tags: gravity

So I usually read, that the falling speed of an object towards the earth is independant of the mass of the object.
Is this actually true?
Shouldn`t the earth fall towards the object as well, therefore invalidating the first statement?

I realize that this would not be measureable for objects we can test this on ourselves, unless one uses the moon or similar for calculations.

Comment: Can your specify your question clearly ,i am  not getting,what you mean earth falling .

Comment: In this context Free Fall :) 
If something is in free Fall inside the earths gravitational Field I would assume the reverse is also true, meaning the earth is inside the objects gravitational field.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall